# Where is the terminal in Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch

Just got the BQ and things are good. I just can't find the terminal. Does anyone know how to start it?

Answer (score 6):

It's not installed by default, but is easily installed from the store.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to install it from the store. Just click the "Ubuntu Store" button at the bottom of the Apps scope, then search for "Terminal" and you should find it.

Answer (score 1):

you can install the terminal (ubuntu core app developers) app from the ubuntu store on your phone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I think this qualifies as an answer.  Not necessarily a *good* answer, but it is an answer.  (It says they can install the terminal from the ubuntu store as an app, essentially.)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this: so 'It's not installed by default, but is easily installed from the store.' is a better answer just for adding a photo that actually does not show more than that what I added with (ubuntu core app developers).